# How to implement a callback through a component

Tags: react-native, callback

Basically, i click that stack other page when its open, and i want to implement a callback to update the page if a specific button is pressed inside this second page. My problem is, the button that navigate to the second page is inside a component that is rendering on the first page, like this:

Home page

```
<FlatList
  style={styles.listView}
  contentContainerStyle={styles.listContentView} 
  data={availableJobs}
  keyExtractor={service => service.id.toString()}
  renderItem={({item}) => <CompleteCalls style={styles.listItem} job={item}/>}
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
  ListEmptyComponent={<MyEmpty />}
  horizontal   
/>
```

And the CompleteCalls i had the button to navigate to the second page:

```
<TouchableOpacity 
  style={styles.buttonContainer}
  onPress={() => Navigator.navigate('ServiceDetails', {job} )}>
  <MyText style={styles.button}>Resumo</MyText>
  <MyIcon style={styles.resumeIcon}>{Icons.CHEVRON_RIGHT}</MyIcon> 
</TouchableOpacity>
```

So basically, i'm calling the *ServiceDetails* page inside the *CompleteCalls* component, through the *Home* page.

Inside the *ServiceDetails* i render another component, that is a button, to execute a function.

```
<ActionButton job={job}/>
```

This *ActionButton* just render a button and had a function.

Inside the *ServiceDetails* i can return direct to the *Home* page.

How can i pass a callback through all this just when i click on the *ActionButton*? I need to update the Home page when i got back after clicking the button, but not when i go to another pages, so a Listener is annoying, since its reload the page after every interaction.

Comment: I didn't get you clearly.
Maybe you want do something like:
<ActionButton job={job} onClick={this.onClickCallback.bind(this)}/>
Are you?

Comment: Actually, ActionButton is another component, that is receiving *job* as props and rendering a react native button inside ServiceDetails. So the button itself is in ActionButton

Comment: What's your question? Or where do you want to call the callback?

Comment: I need to reload the home page, but the navigation button is located inside a component, so i need to call it when i leave the second page, but its not directly connected with the home page

Comment: You have: Home Screen -----> Second Page ,  one button inside the SecondPage, you want to call callback when you click the button in the secondPage? The difficulty is you can not get "instance" of the HomeScreen, is it?

Comment: Not really, i have Home -> Second page, but the button that render the second page is inside a component, that renders in home, I want to reload the home when i come back from the second page, but my navigation from the home is not in home itself but in a component

Comment: "The difficulty is you can not get "instance" of the HomeScreen, is it?" Yeah, this

Comment: I'm not clear what's the "renders in home" means, but if you have utilized Redux, it's very easy.